# polyval: from Matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab

I would like to use in R the following expression given in Matlab:

```
 y1=polyval(p,end_v);
```

where p in Matlab is:

```
 p = polyfit(Nodes_2,CInt_interp,3);
```

Right now in R I have:

```
p <- lm(Spectra_BIR$y ~ poly(Spectra_BIR$x,3, raw=TRUE))
```

But I do not know which command in R corresponds to the polyval from Matlab.

Many thanks!

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Basically, I want to calculate a polynomial fit (3rd degree) in a restricted range of data and then  I want to use this function to extrapolate the data to a huge interval of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact equivalence in R for `polyfit` and `polyvar`, as these MATLAB routines are so primitive compared with R's statistical tool box.

In MATLAB, `polyfit` mainly returns polynomial regression coefficients (covariance can be obtained if required, though). `polyvar` takes regression coefficients `p`, and a set of new `x` values to predict the fitted polynomial.

In R, the fashion is: use `lm` to obtain a regression model (much broader; not restricted to polynomial regression); use `summary.lm` for model summary, like obtaining covariance; use `predict.lm` for prediction.

So here is the way to go in R:

```
## don't use `$` in formula; use `data` argument
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,3, raw=TRUE), data = Spectra_BIR)
```

Note, `fit` not only contains coefficients, but also essential components for orthogonal computation. If you want to extract coefficients, do `coef(fit)`, or `unname(coef(fit))` if you don't want names of coefficients to be shown.

Now, to predict, we do:

```
x.new <- rnorm(5)  ## some random new `x`
## note, `predict.lm` takes a "lm" model, not coefficients
predict.lm(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = x.new))
```

`predict.lm` is much much more powerful than `polyvar`. It can return confidence interval. Have a read on `?predict.lm`.

There are a few sensitive issues with the use of `predict.lm`. There have been countless questions / answers regarding this, and you can find the root question to which I often close those questions as duplicated:

- [Getting Warning: “ 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 32 rows” on predict.lm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27464893/4891738)
- [Predict() - Maybe I'm not understanding it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9028662/4891738)

So make sure you get the good habit of using `lm` and `predict` at the early stage of learning R.

---

**Extra**

It is also not difficult to construct something identical to `polyvar` in R. The function `g` in my answer [Function for polynomials of arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40442584/4891738) is doing this, although by setting `nderiv` we can also get derivatives of the polynomial.

Comment: Wow! It works and many thanks for your advice, really excited to use R!

Comment: Done! Yes, I am absolutely new both with R and here! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

r:

```
library(polynom)
predict(polynomial(1:3), c(5,7,9))
[1]  86 162 262
```

matlab ([official example](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyval.html?searchHighlight=polyval&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)):

```
p = [3 2 1];
polyval(p,[5 7 9])
ans =    86   162   262
```